# How to write Junit test case for spring boot:

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, junit, jdbctemplate

```
@RequestMapping("/getSUID/{pid}")
public List<StudyUID> index(@PathVariable("pid") String pid) {
    System.out.println("pid"+pid);
    String nquery=QueriesUtil.getQuery("STUDY_UID_TEST", true);
    nquery=nquery.replace("<:PID>", pid);
    System.out.println(nquery);
    return jdbcTemplate.query(nquery, (rs, rowNum) -> new StudyUID( 
            rs.getInt("PERSON_ID"),
            rs.getString("MODALITY"),
            rs.getString("STUDY_UID"),
```

how to write a junit test case for it? i have tried using MockMvc but still facing errors regarding writing @test.
Does anyone have any suggestions on how I might achieve this using JUnit and Mockito?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: How do you use MockMVC and what are the errors?

Comment: error is :"org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc.perform(org.springframework.test.web.servlet.RequestBuilder)" because "this.mockMvc" is null"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the issues I see here is that your controller is doing all the work - getting a query, setting it up, executing it, and returning the results from the API call.  Doing all these things in one place makes it hard to test.  That also raises a question - what exactly are you trying to test?  And what issues are you running into?

You might want to look at refactoring it to use a [layered architecture](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/PresentationDomainDataLayering.html) instead.  API -> Service Layer -> Repository layer.

This might be a cleaner structure, and you can then test layers independently:

1. Check that the API calls the correct service layer method with the correct parameters.
2. Check that the service layer calls the repository with the correct arguments.
3. Check that the repository creates the correct query.

Alternatively, you could also do integration testing - just invoke the API and make sure that the correct result is returned.

Also, be wary of using String replacement in your queries.  Rather have a look at PreparedStatement (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html).